# BigQuery financial calculation - Round issues

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, udf

I have a real issue with BigQuery and dealing with financial calculations. It seems to be off by pennies depending on the query, which won't work for my needs. Here's an example. Consider this very simple data set:

> TOT_AMT,DLY_AMT,SUN_AMT,CREDIT_COPIES,UNIT_COST_DLY,UNIT_COST_SUNDAY,DAILY_COPIES,SUNDAY_COPIES
>   81.91,16.58,65.33,15,1.105,4.355,1,1
>   10.67,0.0,10.67,3,1.245,3.555,0,1
>   24.74,8.16,16.58,3,1.36,5.525,2,1
>   38.03,0.0,38.03,9,0.0,4.225,0,1

Now one would thing doing basic rounding and testing wouldn't be too difficult, but unfortunately it is. I've tried a variety of methods, as outlined below. I was only able to get one query close. Here's a query to run:

```
SELECT
  TOT_AMT,
  ROUND(ROUND(UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *10000)/10000 + ROUND(UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES * 10000)/10000,2) AS TOT_AMT_calc1,
  ROUND( ( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES * 100 ) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES * 100 ) )/100, 2) AS TOT_AMT_calc2,
  ROUND( ( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES ) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES ) ), 2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_FULL,
  ROUND( ( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100 ) ), 2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_FULL2,
  ( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES ) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES ) ) AS TOT_AMT_calc_FULL_NOROUND,
  ROUND(ROUND( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *1000) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *1000) )/1000,2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_thousand,
  ROUND(ROUND( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100) )/100,2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_works
FROM
  `my_project.my_table`
```

The output of this, is shockingly found in this dataset:

> TOT_AMT,TOT_AMT_calc1,TOT_AMT_calc2,TOT_AMT_calc_FULL,TOT_AMT_calc_FULL2,TOT_AMT_calc_FULL_NOROUND,TOT_AMT_calc_thousand,TOT_AMT_calc_works
>   81.91,81.9,81.9,81.9,8190.0,81.9,81.9,81.9
>   10.67,10.66,10.66,10.67,1066.5,10.665000000000001,10.66,10.67
>   24.74,24.73,24.73,24.74,2473.5,24.735000000000003,24.73,24.74
>   38.03,38.02,38.02,38.02,3802.5,38.025,38.02,38.03

As you can see, the only way to correctly get the rounding one would expect for basic financial calculations is to use this functionality:

```
ROUND(ROUND( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100) )/100,2)
```

I need something to fully work that would ensure a perfect calculation for financials. My main desire to times by more than 100 (10,000) can be outlined in this issue on the BigQuery issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906014

Alas, this doesn't work either and round ceases to function as it should.

Any additional insights would be greatly appreciated. I need a repeatable and accurate way to calculate true financials and BigQuery round is failing even on small numbers.  Would a UDF work better?

*** UPDATE ***
Did some additional testing by casting and exporting table as integers. First basically by multiplying by 100, and a second time multiplying by 10000. It appears BigQuery stores Integer as int64 which has similar rounding issue. With a table where all integers are multiplied by 10,000, the only way I could get an accurate result was essentially the same method as in float64. Namely rounding at the float values multiplied by 100.

```
SELECT
  TOT_AMT,
  ROUND((( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES) )/10000 ),2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_fail1,
  ((( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES) )/10000 )) AS TOT_AMT_calc_fail2,
  (ROUND(( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES) )/100 )/100) AS TOT_AMT_calc_works3
FROM
  `my_project.my_table`
```

I even tried re-casting to no affect. Casting back to float doesn't seem to do anything because it appears INT64 reacts the same as FLOAT64.

Comment: Side note, even excel had the rounding issue. With the answer below I was able to properly gain the correct value despite rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

After interacting with the Google team and looking up rounding errors in float, I have found a solution that is quite accurate. It allows me to store my values as float in BigQuery, but

```
SELECT
  TOT_AMT,
  ROUND(ROUND(UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *10000)/10000 + ROUND(UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES * 10000)/10000,2) AS TOT_AMT_calc1,
  ROUND( ( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES * 100 ) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES * 100 ) )/100, 2) AS TOT_AMT_calc2,
  ROUND( ( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES ) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES ) ), 2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_FULL,
  ROUND( ( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100 ) ), 2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_FULL2,
  ( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES ) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES ) ) AS TOT_AMT_calc_FULL_NOROUND,
  ROUND(ROUND( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *1000) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *1000) )/1000,2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_thousand,
  ROUND(ROUND( ( UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100) + ( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *100) )/100,2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_mostly_works,
  ROUND( ( FLOOR(UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *1000000000) + FLOOR( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *1000000000) ) / 1000000000+.005,2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_WORKS
FROM
  `my_project.table`
```

The line that matters is here:

> ROUND( ( FLOOR(UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES
>   *1000000000) + FLOOR( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *1000000000) ) / 1000000000+.005,2) AS TOT_AMT_calc_WORKS

This removes the floating point error, turns the float into nanoseconds, removes all garbage after each multiplication, and gives me an accurate result.

If I wanted 3 decimal places for my result, I'd change this line as follows:

> ROUND( ( FLOOR(UNIT_COST_DLY * DAILY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES
>   *1000000000) + FLOOR( UNIT_COST_SUNDAY * SUNDAY_COPIES * CREDIT_COPIES *1000000000) ) / 1000000000+.0005,4) AS TOT_AMT_calc_WORKS

This method allows me to store all my values in BigQuery as float, but perform operations at run-time until Google adds the decimal format.  :)